# Pygame animation/event loop and flask-socketio

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, pygame, raspberry-pi

I have been working on a Raspberry Pi powered photobooth that is controlled via a web interface on a user's smartphone as my first RPi project.

The booth itself has a built in display that has a pygame view to give an animated guide and countdown when taking pictures. It uses flask-socketio (http://flask-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to handle client connections and input events from the user via the smartphone.

Pygame needs to be on the app's main thread, and so does socketio, so my problem is that I can't get socketio to work if displaying the pygame view.

My original logic was to have socketio events create an event like so:

```
@socketio.on('connect', namespace'/photo')
def client_connect():
    evnt = pygame.event.Event(gui.INFOEVENT, msg="client_connect")
    pygame.event.post(evnt)
```

and then catch this event in the pygame thread:

```
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if (event.type is gui.INFOEVENT and event.msg == "client_connect"):
           # welcome client on photobooth screen and start guide
```

Note: I haven't checked the syntax on this and it might be wrong.

Does anyone know how I might achieve this? And if so, is my logic half-way there?

I am struggling to get my head around threads and queues and whilst I have learned a tonne, this 'fun' project is slowly wearing me down! Very grateful for any help.

-Andrew

Answer (score 1):

Three problems:

1. `pygame.event.Event` instances don't have a `tpe` attribute. I think you mean:

   ```
   if (event.type is gui.INFOEVENT and event.type == client_connect):
   ```
2. A pygame event (or any other python object)'s type attribute can't simultaneously point to `gui.INFOEVENT` and `client_connect` at the same time, unless the two values are the same (which makes the second check redundant).
3. `client_connect` as a variable is never declared anywhere. I think you mean `"client_connect"`.

However, pygame events can have arbitary attributes associated with them, so you can solve problem two by changing the second use of `event.type` (that stores client_connect) to any other value.

<sub>Note: I am not Familiar with `socketio`</sub>

Comment: Number 1 was indeed a typo (now fixed.) I am not copying the code and pasting it into the SO editor, but rather typing it from the screen of the raspberry pi (backwards I know)!

Thanks for the other info.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I couldn't find an answer to this but here's what I decided to do.

Instead of creating a GUI on the photobooth itself using a separate lib such as pygame with all the intricacies of threads and whatnot, I decided to create a separate route within my socketio app which I will load within a kiosk mode browser on the Raspberry Pi itself at runtime.

From there, my intention is that as the user interacts with the booth using their smartphone (via the index route) and events are fired back to the server (RPi), the server will deal with those interactions and additionally emit events to the local GUI via a different namespace.

These events can trigger animations, transitions or a countdown etc. on the 'local GUI'.

The only issues might be with performance and smooth animations as the interface requires a browser to be running, and an issue to work out when there is more than one user connected to the booth (though there could be a hardware issue in itself there if two clients try to access the camera at the same time, but that's another story!)

Best

Andrew